# Android tab listener wont refresh on selected tab

Tags: android, tabs, actionlistener, ontouchlistener

I hope you can help, I can't seem to get the current tab to reload if a tab is currently selected and then a user click on it again, could someone point out what I'm doing and perhaps modify my code to show me what I'm doing wrong as I have viewed a lot of threads on here and via google but now one seems to know the answer, that or I'm just dumb :D thank you :)

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);


// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
          .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
          .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
          .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
   // Log.d(debugTag, "onTabChanged: tab number=" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());

    switch (tabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
    case 0:
        //do what you want when tab 0 is selected
            test();
        break;


    case 1:
        //do what you want when tab 1 is selected
        break;
    default:

        break;
    }
}
});     
}

public void test (){

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("Warning");
alert.setMessage("You are about to self-destruct!");
alert.show();
}
```

Comment: no problem we can do it , can you tel me onTabChange Listner working properly or not in above code.

Comment: Hey thanks, well when you click on the tab the message appears, once the message is dismissed and you click on the same tab while it's still selected it will not show the message again. But if you go to another tab and then back it works fine. I would like to call the oncreate() when click on the tab that is highlighted. I hope this makes :)

Comment: k first create one varible "private int tabposition" and setter getter methods in Application class.

Comment: below I will paste code please go through..................

Comment: I'm away from my computer at the moment, would you give me a brief description and I will try it when I get home? I have spent ages trying to work this out and no where on the net (where I have looked) knows the answer, I thought this would be common :( I appreciate the help by the way!

Comment: k I posted answer,  just I am implementing my logic in tab click event.

Answer (score 0):

First create one variable in application class like below:

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application {
    public int displayTab = 0;

    public int getDisplayTab() {
        return displayTab;
    }

    public void setDisplayTab(int displayTab) {
        this.displayTab = displayTab;
    }
}
```

and modify your Activity as below:

```
    public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {


    GlobalClass globel;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    globel = (GlobalClass) getApplication();

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);


    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(globel.getDisplayTab());


//Here Handling first tab click 
         getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                test();
                            Log.d("Clickedddddddddddd", "1"
                                    + getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag());
                            HelloTabWidget.this.finish();
                            globel.setDisplayTab(0);
                            Intent i = new Intent(HelloTabWidget.this, HelloTabWidget.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                        }
                    });

    }
    public void test (){

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Warning");
    alert.setMessage("You are about to self-destruct!");
    alert.show();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate this, I will give it a go when I'm next at my computer :)

Comment: Hey just got back to my computer, this is throwing an uncaught exception, I have tried to debug it, if you get time cheeky I know would you take a look?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3591433/HelloTabWidget.zip

Comment: United Kingdom, just started Android dev, a little different to what I'm use to. I see you work on Java/Android, have any public projects?